# How to build routes only to action and to controller with id?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to build two routes only to action and to controller with id, keeping the default.

I have to access:

1. www.mysite.com/MyController/MyAction/{OptionalId}
2. www.mysite.com/MyController/{OptionalId}
3. www.mysite.com/MyActionFromHomeController

I was able to create routes to work with first and the third point, but not for the second. Current code:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OnlyActionToHomeController",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home" },
            constraints: new { noConflictingControllerExists = new NoConflictingControllerExists() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

public class NoConflictingControllerExists : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, bool> _cache = new Dictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path;

        if (path == "/" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return false;

        if (_cache.ContainsKey(path))
            return _cache[path];

        IController ctrl;

        try
        {
            var ctrlFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
            ctrl = ctrlFactory.CreateController(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, values["action"] as string);
        }
        catch
        {
            _cache.Add(path, true);
            return true;
        }

        var res = ctrl == null;
        _cache.Add(path, res);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did!

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OnlyController",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" } // define the id parameter needs to be integer
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OnlyActionToHomeController",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home" },
            constraints: new { noConflictingControllerExists = new NoConflictingControllerExists() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

public class NoConflictingControllerExists : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, bool> _cache = new Dictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path;

        if (path == "/" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return false;

        if (_cache.ContainsKey(path))
            return _cache[path];

        IController ctrl;

        try
        {
            var ctrlFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
            ctrl = ctrlFactory.CreateController(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, values["action"] as string);
        }
        catch
        {
            _cache.Add(path, true);
            return true;
        }

        var res = ctrl == null;
        _cache.Add(path, res);

        return res;
    }
}
```